# How to append multiple strings in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I am parsing an XML file in Groovy and later I need to append the variables returned.

```
def lmList = slurperResponse.LastGlobal.HeatMap
String appendedString = lmList.country + lmList.ResponseTime + lmList.timeset
```

This doesn't work to append the 3 strings. It just assigns the first string to the right. How to properly implement it in Groovy? I tried `concat` and it threw the following error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChildren.concat() is applicable for argument types: (groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChildren) values: [4468]
Possible solutions: toFloat(), collect(), collect(groovy.lang.Closure)
at
```

Comment: Can you give some example XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to injecteer -

```
def lmList = slurperResponse.LastGlobal.HeatMap
String appendedString = lmList.country.toString() + lmList.ResponseTime.toString() + lmList.timeset.toString()
```

You weren't trying to add strings, you were trying to add nodes the happen to contain strings.

Answer (score 2):

Yor code shall look like:

```
String appendedString = "${lmList.country}${lmList.ResponseTime}${lmList.timeset}"
```

The exception you are getting means, that you are trying to invoke the `plus()/concat()` method which is not provided by `NodeChildren`

Comment: I do like the declarative Your code Shall look like: - very nice :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the xml looks like:

```
def xml = '''
<Root>
    <LastGlobal>
        <HeatMap>
            <Country>USA</Country>
            <ResponseTime>20</ResponseTime>
            <TimeSet>10</TimeSet>
        </HeatMap>
    </LastGlobal>
</Root>
'''
```

Below should give what is expected:

```
def slurped = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
assert slurped.LastGlobal.HeatMap.children()*.text().join() == 'USA2010'
```